# Receiving data inside body from a POST response in a firebase real-time database

Tags: firebase-realtime-database

Does anyone know how to receive data in a POST response sent after making a POST request to Firebase's real-time database? I've gone through its REST API but I couldn't get nothing out of it:

https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/rest/database

Comment: To read data from the Realtime Database you'd use a `GET` request on the correct path. This sounds like a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem): what are you trying to accomplish that requires you to use a `POST` request to receive data?

Comment: Imagine sending in a POST request's body a user and a password, and receiving a jwt token from it. Well, in the project I'm doing the client has services defined which work in this way. I'm using realtime database as a mock, I simply want to replicate that.